# How can I use meteor templates with Bootbox?

Tags: meteor, meteorite, bootbox

How can one use Meteor Templates w/ the bootboxjs library?

ie, I have the following template

**test.html:**

```
<template name="test">
  <input type="text" name="testtext"/>
</template>
```

it has some events,

**test.js:**

```
Template.test.events({
'keyup input[name="testtext"]' : function () { console.log('key up in testtext'); }
});
```

How can you use the template to generate a bootbox modal w/ the events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [bootbox](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/bootboxjs) to your app (via meteorite): `mrt add bootboxjs`
2. You can pass a DOM fragment to bootbox's dialog function. You can get a DOM fragment from [`Spark.render(...)`](https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/d340ca14-d6f2-45a7-bfbe-3006540a0e74)

Example:

```
bootbox.dialog(
  Spark.render(Template.test),
    [{
      "label" : "Ok",
      "class" : "btn-primary",
       "callback": function() {}
    },{
      "label" : "Cancel",
      "class" : "btn",
      "callback": function() {}
    }],
    {
      "header":"Some Dialog box",
      "headerCloseButton":true,
      "onEscape": function() {}
    }
);
```

Bonus Example-- Rendering the html, but without any events:

```
bootbox.dialog(
  Template.test({contextVar:'SomeValue'}), // Set your context values here
    [{
      "label" : "Ok",
      "class" : "btn-primary",
       "callback": function() {}
    },{
      "label" : "Cancel",
      "class" : "btn",
      "callback": function() {}
    }],
    {
      "header":"Some Dialog box",
      "headerCloseButton":true,
      "onEscape": function() {}
    }
);
```

Comment: `Spark.render` got deprecated in favor of `UI.render`. This requires a parent node to passed in wich will make your example not usable anymore. Do you have a clue how to make it work with Meteor 1.0 ?

Comment: @HaNdTriX I no longer work with meteor on a daily basis, most of my answers will decay as meteor evolves. Feel free to edit the correct answers in place.

Answer (score 2):

You could pass Blaze.toHTML(Template.your_dialog_template) to the "messages" attribute of the bootbox.dialog() call, but events won't work.

So the trick could be to inject your template inside the dialog box once it's open, using Blaze.render().

```
bootbox.dialog({
        title: "Title",
        message: '<span/>', // bootbox doesn't accept an empty value
        buttons: {
            success: {
                label: "Save",
                className: "btn-success",
                callback: function () {
                    // do tomething

                }
            }
        }
    }
);

// Inject your template inside the dialog box
Blaze.render(Template.dialog_create_cluster, $('.bootbox-body')[0])
```

Comment: And this does not suffer from the red text mentioned [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_render)? And if it doesn't, what if it changes in the future? I would recommend using `Blaze.remove` when the dialog is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example Meteor app illustrating:

- modal dialogs (bootboxjs)
- mobile detection (detectmobilebrowser + yepnope)
- multi-select (loudev jquery plugin)

https://github.com/alanning/meteor-modal-example

Live example:
  http://modal-example.meteor.com/

Comment: Hmm. that only uses `bootbox.alert(...)` in one place, not quite what I am talking about here. Looking for a good way to use templates within `bootbox.dialog(...)` . Of particular note is that I still havent figured out how to get both events and set the data context (Spark.render(...) gives events, Template.test({context:'foo'}); sets the context, but loses the events) ;

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the `Template.templateName.rendered` and `Template.templateName.events` calls to happen with this approach:

**Fails to execute `rendered` and `events`:**

```
bootbox.dialog
  title: 'title'
  message: Meteor.render -> Template.template(data: data)
  closeButton: true
```

**Executes `rendered` and `events`:**

Render the template in a `div` with `display:none`:

**HTML**

```
<div id="modalContainer">{{> modalTemplate}}</div>
```

Re-render it as necessary by updating its data with `Session.set`:

**Some other template**

```
Session.set 'data', this.data
```

**Modal Template**

```
Template.modalTemplate.helpers
  data: -> Session.get 'data'
```

Display the fully rendered and reactive template with `bootbox.dialog`:

**Another template**

```
bootbox.dialog
  message: $('#modalContainer')
  title: 'title'
  closeButton: true
```

I would rather be able to render the template in the `bootbox.dialog` call, but I couldn't get it to work without some weird `setTimeout` business. I also tried `Spark.render` to no avail. I'm going to look into `bootbox.dialog` to see if a `callback` option would be a helpful addition.

Answer (score 1):

Using the latest version of Meteor you can do the following

```
let box = bootbox.dialog({title:'Title',message:'-'});
box.find('.bootbox-body').remove();
Blaze.renderWithData(template,MyCollection.findOne({_id}),box.find(".modal-body")[0]);
```

If you want the dialog to be reactive use

```
let box = bootbox.dialog({title:'Title',message:'-'});
box.find('.bootbox-body').remove();
Blaze.renderWithData(template,function() {return MyCollection.findOne({_id})},box.find(".modal-body")[0]);
```